# backbone.js router failing in PhoneGap iOS build

Tags: jquery, ios, xcode, cordova, backbone.js

My backbone.js router seems to fail once I try to create a PhoneGap 2.2.0 build on my local machine and also the PhoneGap Build cloud service.

This means none of the internal links and navigation on the app will work although touch events are clearly being triggered.

My app has worked perfectly up until this point, locally through Chrome and the iOS emulator. I can find a lot about jQuery Mobile and conflicts with the backbone.js router but I'm using jQuery 1.8.2 (I've also tested with earlier versions 1.7.0 to 1.8.2).

In the Xcode console I'm getting the error "Failed to load webpage with error: Frame load interrupted" when clicking internal links. I'm using the '/#link' format for internal links in the app.

I'm guessing this might be some kind of iOS/Xcode security feature in the vanilla PhoneGap Xcode project I have set up? But are there any settings I can change to allow this?

Comment: Habe you made this work? I have the same issue now? and seems no one has this

Comment: Hope my answer below helps Harry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I better answer my own question, as I did find a work around after quite a bit of trying. I'll try and answer quickly now but hopefully come back later and improve it. Basically, rather than using standard links embedded in the markup such as

```
<a id="myLink" href="/#link">my link</a>
```

you need to bind the functionality to the link and use the Backbone.js router like so:

```
$('#myLink').tappable(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    application.router.navigate(url, true);

    return false;
});
```

In my case I was already using jquery.tappable.js http://aanandprasad.com/articles/jquery-tappable/ to improve the responsiveness off my UI.

I've also since found another advantage to doing it this way, is if your one-page web-app is hosted in a sub-folder of another site. By forcing your app to use the Backbone.js router you won't have any problems with relative paths breaking your internal links.

I think the reason I had no problems during testing and only once complied into Phonegap, was because I was really testing in the Safari mobile (via a bookmark on the home screen). Once complied it was in a web-view. A native iOS dev might be able to explain this.

Answer (score 0):

You might have more success using this router with Backbone and JQM as it uses JQM events rather than watching for a has change.

https://github.com/azicchetti/jquerymobile-router

Answer (score 0):

friend.
I try anthor way and it works.
just remove splash 
   my link

Comment: <a id="myLink" href="/#link">my link</a>